# $.datetimepicker is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, undefined, datetimepicker

i got a problem with the datetimepicker from this site:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

this is the js-code:

```
var dates = $("#ArrivalStartDatepicker").datetimepicker({

defaultDate: "+lw",

dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',

changeMonth: true,

numberOfMonths: 2,

ampm: true,

stepMinute: 10,

minuteGrid: 10,

onSelect: function (selectedDate) {

// var option = this.id == "ArrivalStartDatepicker" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",

// instance = $(this).data("datetimepicker"),

document.getElementById("TotalLabel").value = $.datetimepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', '2012-05-23');

// instance.settings.dateFormat ||

// $.datetimepicker._defaults.dateFormat,

// selectedDate, instance.settings);

// dates.not(this).datetimepicker("option", option, date);

// document.getElementById("TotalLabel").value = date;

}

});
```

here is my html-code
for the datetimepicker

```
<div class="txtTravel" id="DatetimePickerContainer1">
<input id="ArrivalStartDatetimepicker" type="text" name="datetimepicker" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm am"/>
</div>
```

this is the head of this .aspx-site

```
<%@ Page Title="GH" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GH.aspx.cs" Inherits="GBCalc.GH" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="True"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/timepicker.css" />
    <link href="Styles/base/jquery.ui.base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        div.txtGeneral{position: relative; left: 110px; top: 55px; margin-top: 1.5px;}
        div.lblGeneral{position:relative; left: -6px; top: 75px; margin: 1.5px; font-size: small;}
        div.txtJob{position: absolute; top: 92px; left: 520px; }
        div.lblJob{position: absolute; top: 92px; left: 370px; font-size: small;}
        div.txtTravel{position: relative; left: 200px; top: 70px;}
        div.lblTravel{position: relative; left: 0px; top: 90px; margin: 1.5px; font-size: small;}
        div.txtWork{position: relative; left: 250px; top: 0px;}
        div.lblWork{position: relative; left: 20px; top: 20px; margin: 1.5px; font-size: small;}
        div.lblMisc{position: relative; left: -5px; top: -1px; margin: 1.5px; font-size: small;}
        div.txtMisc{position: relative; left: 170px; top: -20px;}
    </style>
    <script src="Scripts/ui/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui/molschaua.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

        <asp:DropDownList ID="SubsidiaryCalcDropDownList" runat="server" 
        ToolTip="Subsidiary maker of the Calculation">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br /> 
    <div id="MyAccordion">
```

the problem is that the datetimepicker is shown if I open the site but as soon as I select a date or a time firebug throws an error called "$.datetimepicker is undefined"

this error is thrown in this line "`document.getElementById("TotalLabel").value = $.datetimepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', '2012-05-23');`"

I wanted to passthrough the value I selected in the datetimepicker to my codebehind c# methods.
where is my problem?

I imported all of the needed js files and in my opinion i got the right order how I imported them.

greetz

Tobi

Comment: have you included the js file of that datetime picker

Comment: +1 to the above comment, and also, you're specifying 'yy-mm-dd', but providing 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [parseDate method](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) is not from the plugin, it's from jquery ui.
Replace `$.datetimepicker.parseDate(...)` with `$.datepicker.parseDate(...)`:

```
document.getElementById("TotalLabel").value = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', '2012-05-23');
```